# can someone explain me whether an expression within the for loops header is an expression statement or an expression

Tags: javascript, for-loop, expression, ecmascript-2020

**I read the ECMAScript Specification about the for loop's syntax and all. and now i need to know whether the `Expressions` within a for loop's header are `ExpressionStatements` or just `Expressions` im asking this because after every `Expression` we write a semicolon `;` except for the last one**

```
for ( <Expression>; <Expression>; <Expression> ) <Statement>
```

so now i need to know whether the `<Expressions>` written within the below `for loop's` header are **Expression statements** or just **Expressions**

```
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) console.log(i);
```

Comment: what is an ExpressionStatement ? If you can extend with a comma operator, it's an expression.

Comment: an `ExpressionStatement` is an Expression with a `Semicolon ;` after it

Comment: what do yu mean

Comment: The ; break up the expressions, unclear why it makes any difference to you that it is missing. I been coding JavaScript since 1998 and have never asked myself why it would be missing. I do like `for(;;)`

Comment: "ExpressionStatement" isn't a widely-used term in JavaScript, so who's to say what is and isn't one except the person defining the term?

Comment: @epascarello well in that case the header of the for loop will be having empty statements

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm not the most knowledgeable, but from my research:

`i = 0;` is a statement (an ExpressionStatement, technically a statement but consists solely of an expression), where `i = 0` is the expression (AssignmentExpression).

`i < 5;` is a statement (another ExpressionStatement), where `i < 5` is the expression (BinaryExpression).

`i++` is an UpdateExpression, which in the specification seems to be just a simple expression as can be seen [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-expressions).

So the first two are technically statements while the last one is an expression.